Getting Unhandled Runtime Error in NextJs
I am getting Unhandled Runtime Error in my Nextjs Website during the development
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
**
Warning: **Text content did not match. Server: "160 mins ago" Client: "161 mins ago"
error image
I have tried to debug by searching NextJs documentation but getting no result as per my issue

It looks like a Hydration error is coming due to the difference in data between the client and server side.
Could you please try to check if you are using any component which has different data for the client and server-side?
Also if you share some component details, then I will be able to help more on this.
In the meantime, you can get more details regarding this on the given link of NextJS.
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
